# How to insert into a row, a value from other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I have 3 Mysql tables.

A table with the classes and the labs and their id.

A table with the teachers_list and their subject.
A table which is going to be the schedule.**

I want to randomly assign one of the physicists to one of the physics labs on my third table which is going to be the schedule.

```
INSERT INTO schedule(teacher_name, class_id)
VALUES (select teacher_name from teachers_list where subject="Physicist” order by rand() limit 1, 

select id from lab_list where lab="Physics_lab" order by rand() limit 1);
```

**This one doesn't work :(

Can you help me?**

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also, read this guide on how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you want the `insert ... select` syntax, along with a subquery:

```
insert into schedule(teacher_name, class_id)
select 
    (
        select teacher_name 
        from teachers_list 
        where subject = 'Physicist'
        order by rand()
        limit 1
    ),
    id
from lab_list
where lab = 'Physics_lab'
```

Comment: That's very very helpful! It works!
Could I somehow ensure that in the next queries the same teacher won't be selected for the other class?

Comment: @ChristosTsaki; probably, but your question totally lacks the information that could help telling how to do this. I would suggest accepting this answer, then asking a new question, adding a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates what you actually want (that is, sample data from the involved tables, along with the desired results - as tabular text).